# How to prevent automation test cases in android release APK?

Tags: android, selenium, kotlin, automated-tests

Automation tools like **(Robotium、Espresso、UiAutomator2、Appium)**

Comment: What is the scenario, and what are you expecting, pls post the question clearly to have a look?

Comment: In my Case: Some One run automation test cases continuously and do infinite registration with different different mobile number. In that case OUR Back-end send OTP to every mobile number. So want to prevent automation test cases in release APK. Please Give me any solution Thank you!

Comment: @AbiSaran hey any idea regarding this

Comment: Still, I dont get it clearly, but, are you building the .apk file including automation test cases?  in that case, why can't you remove from those test cases from .apk file.   Otherwise, change or delete the name and path of .apk file from the automation test cases.

Comment: No, I need to secure like this automation test